# Raised domain functional lever from 2003 to 2008 but one server didn't upgrade and now doesn't sync

Tags: dns

I have recently raised the domain functional lever of my network from 2003 to 2008 but one of the servers did not get that upgrade. That server happens to be a GC too.

I have tried to manually raise on that server but no luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the other DC system clock had wrong time. Fixing that resolved the issue.